# Cislunar and deep space background radiation

Tags: cosmic-radiation

What is the least amount of daily radiation an astronaut can expect in cislunar space and/or in deep space?

Answer (score 1):

This graph from JPL https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpeg/PIA17601.jpg gives a good comparison of equivalent radiation dose on different space missions. It’s definitely safer to stay home and out of radiology departments as far as radiation exposure goes.

Note the vertical axis is logarithmic.

[image]